# Set background color of a specific control

Tags: winapi, colors, background, dialog, controls

I have searched the net looking for a way to set background color a dialog control.

I have managed to do this with this code:

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;
    SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255,255,255));
    SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,0,0));

    if (hbrBkgnd == NULL)
    {
        hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
    }
    return (INT_PTR)hbrBkgnd;
}
```

However, what I am actually looking for is to color only a specific static control, not all the static controls I have in my dialog. Is there anyway to do this? Perhaps set the hdc to something using GetDlgItem(hdlg,"IDC_MYCONTROL") ?

-- UPDATE

After the suggestions I ended up with this :

```
case WM_CTLCOLORSTATIC:
{
    HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) lParam;
    HWND hWnd =  (HWND)lParam;
    HWND dlg =GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_STATIC2);
    if (hWnd == dlg)
    {
        SetTextColor(hdcStatic, RGB(255,255,255));
        SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,0,0));
    }
    if (hbrBkgnd == NULL)
    {
        hbrBkgnd = CreateSolidBrush(RGB(0,0,0));
    }
    return (INT_PTR)hbrBkgnd;
}
```

And it seems that even if SetBkColor is run nothing changes on the dialog, leading on the wierd problem described below.

Comment: So I managed to compare the two using an if statement, and match the correct control. However, SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,0,0)); even if its called only only on the correct control, it colors both controls (well not exactly, it makes it so that the text only has a white background, and the whole control box has a black background. This happens to both controls) . What can I do?

Comment: If the hwnd doesn't match, you shouldn't be handling the message - instead, defer to the default handler.

Comment: Got it working after all, tiny mistake caused this, if you look at the line  HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) lParam; it should be  HDC hdcStatic = (HDC) wParam;

Comment: `GetDlgCtrlID ((HWND) lParam)` gets you the ID of the control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check lParam matches the handle to the child that you want to change the colour of.

Comment: So I managed to compare the two using an if statement, and match the correct control. However, SetBkColor(hdcStatic, RGB(0,0,0)); even if its called only only on the correct control, it colors both controls. What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

The HWND is passed to the dialog proc so you could;

```
 HWND hWnd = (HWND) lParam;
 if (hWnd == GetDlgItem(hdlg, "IDC_MYCONTROL")) {
     ...
```

Comment: This is wrong. The hwnd is the hwnd of the dialog. lParam is the handle to the child. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787524(v=vs.85).aspx